# JDK8 API Default Concurrecy

Tags: java-8

I have to write an API on top of Existing JDK8 Implementation having given the Task to Improve Scalability of Core Java Code.

I have tried using Sleep API which has two arguments, but since the CPU Clock is less accurate, it is of no use.

Can I use Thread Group and use For Loop to Improve Scalability?

Comment: this is a bit too vague to get proper help. please elaborate. what are you trying to accomplish exactly.

Comment: You tried to “Improve Scalability of Core Java Code” by “using Sleep API”?

Comment: What iam trying to accomplish is creating timeslicing between threads to allow each thread to sleep for a minimilistic period of time so that other threads get to spawn the method. simple way to create multithreading between threads accessing the method.

Comment: i dont know how you felt it vague. kindly elaborate.

Comment: I would leave it to the OS to do the multi-threading and time slicing.  BTW The `sleep` with two arguments just calls the sleep with 1 argument i.e. it doesn't do anything different.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that a ThreadGroup,a loop or sleep will make any difference to the scalability of your solution.